# Terminate called in move assignment of std::thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, terminate

I have a multi-threaded application used by multiple users. For some users, running the application results in

```
terminate called without an active exception
Aborted
```

Running the application with GDB results in the following output:

```
Thread 1 ... received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
__GI__raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
51       ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c: No such file or directory.
(gdb) where
#0 _GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ./sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
#1 0x00007f46925e9921 in GI_abort () at abort.c:79
#2 0x0000744692404957 in ?? (from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.50.6
#3 0x00007F4692fe2ae6 in ?? (from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.50.6
#4 0x00007F4692fe2b21 in std::terminate() ()
  from /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.50.6
#5 0X000056407cb17783 in std::thread::operator=(std::thread&&) ()
...
```

Looking online, the error seems to be due to improperly handling the cleanup of a thread (one of the threads is still joinable). The code below is an example of the code found in the application.

Watch Dog

```
class WatchDog {
  std::thread t_;
  std::atomic<bool> run_;

public:
  WatchDog(){};

  void Init() { t_ = std::thread(&WatchDog::Log, this); }

  void Log() {

    run_ = true;
    while (run_) {
      std::cout << "Operational" << std::endl;
      std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
      // throw;
    }
  }

  void Stop() { run_ = false; }

  ~WatchDog() {
    if (t_.joinable())
      t_.join();
  }
};
```

Main

```
int main() {
  WatchDog dog;
  dog.Init();

  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
  dog.Stop();
}
```

The example stripped application runs without failure and the RAII idiom was followed in the actual application as well. Looking back closely at the GDB results though, it seems that the terminate call was made in the move assignment constructor itself to `t_` itself. Any explanations on how this could occur and suggestions for debugging it? Appreciate your help.

---

## Edit

Thanks, Slava, BitTickler, cdhowie.. I wasn't aware of `std::optional`. I noticed that I have made my design mistake a couple of other places and so wanted to make a ThreadWrapper class. Credit to https://thispointer.com/c11-how-to-use-stdthread-as-a-member-variable-in-class/. Extended it with the ability to pass `this` to `std::thread` as I do require access to the WatchDog class.

```
class ThreadWrapper {
public:
  // Delete copy constructor
  ThreadWrapper(const ThreadWrapper &) = delete;

  // Delete assignment constructor
  ThreadWrapper &operator=(const ThreadWrapper &) = delete;

  // Parameterized Constructor
  template <class F, class... Args>
  explicit ThreadWrapper(F&& func, Args &&... args)
      : thread_(std::forward<F>(func), std::forward<Args>(args)...) {}

  // Move constructor
  ThreadWrapper(ThreadWrapper &&obj) : thread_(std::move(obj.thread_)) {}

  // Move Assignment Constructor
  ThreadWrapper &operator=(ThreadWrapper &&obj) {
    if (thread_.joinable()) {
      thread_.join();
    }
    thread_ = std::move(obj.thread_);
    return *this;
  }

  ~ThreadWrapper() {
    if (thread_.joinable()) {
      thread_.join();
    }
  }

private:
  std::thread thread_;
};
```

Would a ThreadWrapper object held in the `WatchDog` class now be safe from a potential call to `Init` twice? Planning to initialize threadwrapper_ in the WatchDog constructor but more for my own knowledge. Thanks again everyone.

```
threadwrapper_ = ThreadWrapper(&WatchDog::Log, this);
```

Comment: Does this sample code exhibit the same failure on user machines? If not, the removed code is probably relevant.

Comment: We can't really help you fix code that's working.  Can we get a [mre] that actually reproduces the issue?

Comment: What happens if you rewrite `void Init() { t_ = std::thread(&WatchDog::Log, this); }` like this: `void Init() { t_ = std::move(std::thread(&WatchDog::Log, this)); }`?

Comment: Could it be true that somewhere in the code you call the `Init()` method on an uninitialized (not constructed) object?

Comment: @BitTickler that is functionally equivalent

Comment: @alter igel Probably :) I still wait for the day where I find a valid use of that `std::move()` function :)

Comment: @BitTickler try writing code with `std::unique_ptr` and you'll get a feel for it.

Comment: @BitTickler You usually need it to force moving from something that isn't an lvalue. For example, if you are calling a function that accepts an argument by value and you have a local value you want to pass in without making a copy. `some_fn(std::move(some_local))`  Moving from an rvalue/temporary is implicit, when possible.

Comment: @RolliePollie as S.M. has pointed out in their answer, you almost certainly are trying to assign to a `std::thread` that still owns a running thread. You need to ensure that that doesn't happen. What do these threads represent? In your context, is it always a mistake to try and over-write an active `WatchDog` thread? Can these threads be shut-down quickly without consequences?

Comment: Disable move constructor and move assignment operator of class `WatchDog`  and see if you get compilation errors. Most probably somewhere in the code there is assignment to class `WatchDog` itself

Answer (score 3):

[std::thread::operator=](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/operator%3D)

> If `*this` still has an associated running thread (i.e. `joinable() == true`), call `std::terminate()`.

It looks like your `t_` has an associated running thread, but your not real code does not show this.

Comment: Thank you. This makes sense to me. Let me see if I can try to find out why I would be calling Init twice in the code. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To build on the existing answer, what's most likely happening is that you're calling `Init()` twice on the same object, which causes the existing (joinable) thread to be assigned to, which is not allowed.  Consider redesigning this class with a new interface.

- `Init()` should implicitly happen on construction.
- `Stop()` should implicitly happen on destruction.
- Make `Log()` private and const-correct.

With this implementation, there is no possibility to accidentally call `Init()` twice, and cleanup happens automatically on destruction.  (In your implementation, if you forget to call `Stop()` then the thread will never join because `run_` is never set to false.)

If you want the ability to have a "maybe-active `WatchDog`" then you can simply use `std::optional<WatchDog>`.

```
class WatchDog {
  std::atomic<bool> run_;
  std::thread t_;

public:
  WatchDog();
  ~WatchDog();

private:
  void Log() const;
};

WatchDog::WatchDog() :
  run_{true},
  t_{&WatchDog::Log, this} {}

void WatchDog::Log() const {
  while (run_) {
    std::cout << "Operational" << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(200));
    // throw;
  }
}

WatchDog::~WatchDog() {
  run_ = false;
  if (t_.joinable()) {
    t_.join();
  }
}
```

With this implementation, your given `main()` becomes:

```
int main() {
    WatchDog dog;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
}
```

If you want more explicit control over the lifetime of the object in a more dynamic setting, that's where `std::optional` comes in:

```
int main() {
    std::optional<WatchDog> dog;
    dog.emplace(); // Replaces Init()
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(2));
    dog.reset(); // Replaces Stop()
}
```

Obviously this will have the same observable behavior as the other `main()` example, but the point is to illustrate how you might create and destroy the object if its lifetime needs to be more complex and not bounded exactly by the lifetime of a value.

This resolves the issue you were having of `Init()` being called twice because `std::optional::emplace()` will destroy the contained value before creating a new one.  Of course, if you only want to ensure that there is an active `WatchDog` (not destroying and creating one unnecessarily) then you could do something like `if (!dog) { dog.emplace(); }`.

As a side note, if `WatchDog::Log` never uses `this` then it can be made `static` and then a particular thread is not tied to a particular `WatchDog` instance.

Comment: In your code it is possible that `WatchDog::Log` would use `run_` before it is initialized.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I'm going to redesign it as suggested.

Comment: 2 stage init of an object instance is a common use case e.g. in embedded programming with exceptions turned off.

Comment: @Slava Indeed, not sure how I missed that -- fixed.

Comment: @BitTickler Sure. That's where `std::optional` can be useful.